# How to create a two-column definition-like table

Tags: tables, alignment

How do I make something like:

```
    **Definition** Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
                   quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatemquia 
                   voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni doloreseos 
                   qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum 
                   quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi 

 **Definition #2** Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
                   quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatemquia
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for the `itemize` environment

Comment: @SorghumBean welcome to the site -- please have a look athe answer below using `tabularx` environment and reducing `column separators` to `4pt` -- the `X column` from `tabularx`  auto adjusts the width of the second column and the first column is right aligned as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
%\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs,lipsum,tabularx}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt} % Default value: 6pt
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{rX}\toprule
        **Signal**          &\lipsum[1] \\
        **Discrimination**  &\lipsum[7] \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\enumitem` package or optional argument of `\item`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    
        \begin{enumerate}[start=1,label={**Definition** \#\arabic*:}]
            \item \lipsum[1]
            \item \lipsum[1]
        \end{enumerate}
    %or
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item[**Definition**] \lipsum[1]
            \item[**Definition** \#2] \lipsum[1]
        \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]